# I need to convert an int[][] to a char[][] or create a char[][] of the same dimensions

Tags: java, arrays, char, int, 2d

I have an int[][] that will be initialized by a file so I don't know the size of it. how can I convert it to a 2D char array or create a char[][] of the same size?

Is this along the right lines? how would I do it?

```
int[][] shade = <a method returns an int[][]>

char[][] converted = new int[shade.length][];
for(int i = 0; i < shade.length; i++) {
    converted[i] = new String[shade[i].length];
    for(int j = 0; j < shade[i].length; j++){
        converted[i][j] = Character.toInt(shade[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the int array is [[1,2]], you want you char array to be ['1','2']  or convert to ASCII?

Answer (score 0):

you can do that :

```
String[][] converted = new String[a.length][];
for(int index = 0; index < a.length; index++) {
    converted[index] = new String[a[index].length];
    for(int subIndex = 0; subIndex < a[index].length; subIndex++){
        converted[index][subIndex] = Integer.toString(a[index][subIndex]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to confirm what kind of char do you need .

I guess you need to convert the int into a char representing  in ASCII, that means 65 will be cast to 'A' , you can just use typecast, like

```
int intvalue=65;
char c=(char)intvalue;//will be 'A'
```

If you want to convert 5 to '5'(But you need to guarantee that intvalue is within [0,9])  ,use

```
int intvalue=5;
char c= = (char) ('0' +  intvalue); // c is now '5';
```

Here is the way of your case from int to char representing in ASCII:

```
public static void main(String agrs[]) {

    int[][] shade = getIntArray();//here is how you 

    char[][] converted = new char[shade.length][shade[0].length];//use the shade's row and column length to declare an char[][] array

    for (int i = 0; i < shade.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < shade[i].length; j++) {
            converted[i][j] = ((char) shade[i][j]);
            System.out.println(converted[i][j]);//out put will be 'A'
        }
    }
}

//here you need to replace it into your own method, now I pretend that I returns a [2][2] array which holds value of 65 ('A')
private static int[][] getIntArray(){

    int[][] array=new int[2][2];
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++){
            array[i][j]=65;
        }
    return array;

}
```